# Odd .txt Reports into Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, report, analysis

I have a .txt report that has account number, address, and credit limit in a report format in .txt

It has page breaks, but it generally looks like this

`Customer   Address           Credit limit
A001        Wendy's           20000
            123 Main Street
            City, State
            Zip`

I want my dataframe to look like this

`Customer Address Credit                            Limit
A001     Wendy's 123 Main Street, City, Statement   20000`

Here is the link to the example csv I'm working through.

http://faculty.tlu.edu/mthompson/IDEA%20files/Customer.txt

I tried to skip lines, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is nothing hard with this format, but it is not csv. So neither Python csv module not pandas `read_csv` can be used. We will have to parse it *by hand*.

The most complex decision is to identify the first  and last line for each customer. I would use:

- first line starts with a word having only uppercase letters and digits, ends with a word containing only digits and is longer than 100 characters
- the block ends at the first blank line

Once this is done:

- first line contains the account number, the name, first line of the address and the account limit
- subsequent lines contain additional lines of the address
- the fields are at fixed positions: [5,19), [23,49), [57,77), [90,end_of_line)

In Python in would give:

```
fieldpos = [(5,19), (23,49), (57,77), (90, -1)]  # position of fields in the initial line 

inblock = False                                  # we do not start inside a block

account_pat = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+\d+\s*$')       # regex patterns are compiled once for performance
limit_pat = re.compile(r'\s*\d+$')

data = []                                        # a list for the accounts

with open(file) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if not inblock:
            if (len(line) > 100):
                row = [line[f[0]:f[1]].strip() for f in fieldpos]
                if account_pat.match(row[0]) and limit_pat.match(row[-1]):
                    inblock = True
                    data.append(row)
        else:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                row[2] += ', ' + line
            else:
                inblock = False

# we can now build a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Account Number', 'Name', 'Address', 'Credit Limit'])
```

It finally gives:

```
   Account Number                 Name                                            Address Credit Limit
0            A001          Dan Ackroyd  Audenshaw, 125 New Street, Montreal, Quebec, H...        20000
1            A123           Mike Atsil  The Vetinary House, 123 Dog Row, Thunder Bay, ...        20000
2            A128            Ivan Aker            The Old House, Ottawa, Ontario, P1D 8D4        10000
3            B001         Kim Basinger    Mesh House, Fish Street, Rouyn, Quebec, J5V 2A9        12000
4            B002       Richard Burton  Eagle Castle, Leafy Lane, Sudbury, Ontario, L3...         9000
5            B004         Jeff Bridges  Arrow Road North, Lakeside, Kenora, Ontario, N...        20000
6            B008          Denise Bent  The Dance Studio, Covent Garden, Montreal, Que...        20000
7            B010          Carter Bout  Removals Close, No Fixed Abode Road, Toronto, ...        20000
8            B022         Ronnie Biggs     Gotaway Cottage, Thunder Bay, Ontario, K3A 6F3         5000
9            C001           Tom Cruise  The Firm, Gunnersbury, Waskaganish, Quebec, G1...        25000
10           C003           John Candy  The Sweet Shop, High Street, Trois Rivieres, Q...        15000
```